# VBA Excel ActiveChart ProtectFormatting

Tags: excel, vba, charts, formatting

I cant write a code that protects my chart from formatting. No error appears but after running the code I can still change formatting of the chart. Maybe you know how I can make it works.

```
 ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
 With ActiveChart
 Application.ActiveChart.ProtectFormatting = True
 End With
```

Comment: How do you format the chart after running this macro?

Answer (score 3):

Except for the basics, your code looks fine to me. You can do this with one line however:

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.ProtectFormatting = True
```

This works for me anyway. Obviously, this doesn't stop the chart being changed through code.